# Image size/resolution for photographic portfolio

Tags: website-design, image-quality, file-format, file-size, photography

I am a developer and I don't know much about web portfolios but:

I'm looking for standard format/size/resolution/quality/compression/file-size for a photographic portfolio website.

For instance, is there a standard defined for each device?

I can imagine a photographer image has to be larger if viewed in a big screen rather from a mobile phone with or without a retina display.

Where can I find a table with standards quality for devices/bandwidth/whatever?

Comment: I think this is a "how long is a piece of string?" question. Farcebork, Instagrump etc will compress the living daylights out of images; dedicated photographic sites will prefer the full-size original, 24mpx, png or jpg 80% quality or higher, with much smaller thumbnails self-generated for gallery/contact sheet views.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very specific.

**Target your final user**.

I think you have a loooot of homework to do.

You could say that a standard number is 1080px, either vertical size on a horizontal monitor or width in a vertical one. A lot of social media websites recommend that number in different forms, square images, vertical or horizontal ones.

Google: [Instagram](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=instagram%20recomended%20dimensions) Do the same with some other photo-sharing websites.

1. Define your user's most used device and resolution: https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats
2. Use CSS Media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
3. Use the picture tag.
4. Use srcset attribute.

So, you probably need several resolutions and let the device choose for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of overthinking it. Aside from the aesthetics of the website presentation, a roll-your-own portfolio (as opposed to a web service) is just a website.

You will want a way to categorize the items; provide a description; provide some eye-catching thumbnail; and then provide the full-size image when the viewer's interest is sufficiently piqued. This is basically an e-commerce site (e.g. wordpress + woocommerce) without commerce elements. As a developer, you could probably make your own lightweight option, but you would find modifying an e-commerce package fairly straightforward.

If the portfolio item is a website, include screencaps of at least 1080p-sized and mobile viewports. Virtually all of your viewers will probably first interact on mobile. For still photography, something sized for 5 or 6 MB compressed file at the most lossless preset is probably sufficient, but you could go larger if you gate-keep a little to prevent front-loading massive images of things people have not yet shown interest in (clicked on).

e-commerce products will handle downsizing based on media queries for you, but if you write your own, you would make (or process on upload) several sizes (i.e. untouched (for zoom); normal (for basic presentation); thumbnail (for list presentation).

Comment: also, regardless of where you wind up putting the portfolio, if you click and can count to six, the file may be too large.

Comment: Honestly I thought that 5MB for a picture in a website is definitely too high

Answer (score 0):

Definitely overthinking this.

Save yourself a load of time, create a Behance account, Flickr, 500px, etc and that's a good start, just upload the photos, let the website handle the resolution and devices.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but this does not answer the question

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't think there's an objective answer to your question. People build websites in many ways, upload photos in many ways, there is no given "standard". In many places, bandwidth is a non-issue nowadays. People stream music and video content all day long, what kind of bandwidth do you need for a few pictures ? If you're looking for a table which will give you exact numbers in pixels as a golden "standard", well good luck with that.